# Jenkins Kubernetes (JCASC) How to set default container to my container instead of JNLP?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, containers, kubernetes-helm, jcasc

I'm using pipelines in Jenkins that are running using JNLP container instead of my container.

I'm using Jenkins as a code (Jenkin Helm chart)

If I add this block to the pipeline -

```
 container('my container') {
}
```

It is using 'my container'.

How do I set it as default to all my pipelines? Do I really need to add this container block all the time?

Comment: @SaiChandraGadde changing the default jnlp pod will make issues since the slave wont be able to conntect to madter using different image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [kubernetes plugin doc](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/) you can change it globally with following code:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      defaultContainer 'maven'
      yamlFile 'KubernetesPod.yaml'
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage('Run maven') {
      steps {
        sh 'mvn -version'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Im using JCASC and jenkins helm chart. How to add to my Podtemplate then? Not inside the pipeline?

Comment: Since it is not mentioned in documentation I don't think there is an option to define default container with `PodTemplate` since this is only definition of pod that should be run.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [issue](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65916) to define a different default jnlp container follow below steps:

1. Go to Configure clouds page -> Kubernetes -> Click on Kubernetes
   Cloud details ... -> Click Advanced -> Default Provider Template
   Name.
2. Use the same name in the Pod Template -> name field.
3. Then set the desired jnlp container template image.

Attaching another [blog](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/cloudbees-ci-on-modern-cloud-platforms/change-the-default-jnlp-image-for-kubernetes-agents-provisioning) for your reference.